# In what context would one prefer to use the CSS display: table properties rather than an HTML table?

Tags: html, css

I read about `display: table`,`display: table-cell`, etc. [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) but it did not go into much detail as to when using these properties would be preferable to using HTML table elements. I'm curious in what situation(s) the CSS display: table properties would be better.

Edit: This question has been marked as a duplicate of this: [CSS display table vs normal HTML Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988203/css-display-table-vs-normal-html-table) but there is actually very little information on why the person asking the question doesn't want to use HTML tables. It's troubleshooting how to use the display:table properties.

Comment: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/tables/

Comment: Are you displaying tabular data? Use the `table` element (additional clue: you're going to use at least 1 `th` - and probably attribute `scope="row"` or `"col"`, elements `thead`, `tbody` and seldomly `col` and `tfoot`). If not tabular data, do you need blocks of same height or elements across many rows but disaplyed as columns? Then use the `display` property with values like `table` or `table-something` on elements unrelated to tables.